# Yii firing multiple queries instead of one

Tags: php, yii

Trying to cut down on the number of queries on my site... Why would a single query run as multiple queries? Is there a way to fix this?

For example, from the following line of code (line 43)...

```
$model = Menu::model()->findAll();
```

We can see in my query log that 4 seperate queries were fired...

[image: Excerpt from query log.]

Or am I just reading this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rows 1, 2 & 4 in your screenshot above are doing database queries.

ActiveRecord in Yii does `SHOW COLUMNS FROM <table>` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` before the query so it knows what columns / column types the table has. In production mode you can turn on schema caching to reduce these queries:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/final.deployment#enabling-schema-caching

Comment: Thank you. Quick question, when I added `'cache'=>array('class'=>'CDbCache'...` it bombed out. When I used `'cache'=>array('class'=>'system.caching.CApcCache'...` it worked. Why does the first not work?

Comment: Did using CDbCache display any error messages? As long as your 'DB' config is correct and you've created the [cache table (or let Yii create it for you)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCache#autoCreateCacheTable-detail) it should work.

Comment: There is an issue with the current yii version which will be fixed in 1.1.11. When you use CDbCache and yii can not connect to database somehow it dies in an endless loop: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/454